# What command do I run to determine what azure terraform provider version I have been using?

Tags: azure, terraform

How do I determine what version of azure terraform provider that I have been using?   I want to remain consistent on the same provider version.   Is there a difference between a provider for Azure or AWS?  My understanding is the provider is downloaded each time with the init command.   Also what is the difference between (version = "=1.34.0") versus (version = "1.16")?   what is the equal sign doing inside the quotes for ver 1.34.0?   Also noticed you can specify > or < certain versions,... what is the reason for doing this?,... is this just to stay away from newer untested versions?

If there is a mistake and you want to revert to the previous configuration after running terrform.  Is there are simple way to start from before the most recent terrafrom change?  Any way to revert to certain dates of terraform changes?,... any way to see what changes were done on which terraform apply or destroy dates?

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of questions, so I'll try to answer them all.

1. What provider version am I using?

Run `terraform version` from the folder you have initialized for a given configuration.  It will show the terraform version and any provider versions.

2. Are there differences in AWS and Azure providers?

Absolutely.  The version numbers have nothing to do with each other.  Check out the provider repos at https://github.com/terraform-providers

3. What does the `version="=1.16.0"` mean?

This is pretty deep, but the basic principle is that you can lock a version in for a provider for consistency.  You never know when a new version could have a breaking change.  About the equals sign, `version=` is setting the version property of the provider. When it's `"=1.16.0"` it's saying the version should always equal 1.16.0 exactly.  There are other options like `"~>1.16.0"` or `">1.16.0"` among others.  Read here for more info - https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/providers.html

4. Reverting changes

You should be using something like git to store your infrastructure changes. You might also want to use a system like Azure Dev Ops that locks releases to git commit versions.  Essentially, if you deploy a change that breaks something, you can roll back your code to a prior commit and run it again to change it back.  There is no "undo" option.

Hope this helps!!